# Error starting Custom JMX Server on 0.0.0.0

Tags: java, linux, networking, rmi, jmx

I am starting our JMX server using the following code:

```
Integer port = 8291;
JMXServiceURL url = new JMXServiceURL("service:jmx:rmi://0.0.0.0:"+ (port+100) +"/jndi/rmi://0.0.0.0:"+ port +"/jmxrmi");
```

On our application startup we are getting:

```
Caused by: java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 0.0.0.0; nested exception is:
        java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:601)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(TCPChannel.java:198)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(TCPChannel.java:184)
        at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.newCall(UnicastRef.java:322)
        at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.bind(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.jndi.rmi.registry.RegistryContext.bind(RegistryContext.java:120)
        ... 53 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:333)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:193)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:182)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:366)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:525)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:475)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:372)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:186)
        at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIDirectSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIDirectSocketFactory.java:22)
        at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIMasterSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIMasterS
```

This works in windows but fails on linux.  There is nothing bound to 8291.  (I verified this with a `netstat -anp` )

Does anybody know why this is failing?

FYI.  We are starting a custom JMX server because of the firewall (see [here](http://olegz.wordpress.com/2009/03/23/jmx-connectivity-through-the-firewall/) for explanation why)

Comment: Not quire sure if this helps you, but I've got the same outcome on my linux machine.

Comment: However it fails also on MS Windows 2003 Server, which is different than your experience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found [a note which might help you](http://pub.admc.com/howtos/jmx/jmx.html):

> With Sun's JMX Remote JMX RI, the
>   hostname/ip-addr segment is not used
>   to limit the target IP address/name,
>   as it should. It must just match any
>   valid IP address/name for this host
>   (including localhost or 127.0.0.1),
>   and it will then listen to IPADDR_ANY.
>   You will have to do custom coding (or
>   use an IP filtering or firewall
>   product) to limit the listen
>   addresses.

So it looks like you could just replace `0.0.0.0` with `localhost` and it would still listen on all network interfaces.

BTW, I tried your code with this change, but now I get another exception (a different one though).